# How to get a Queryset from a list of IDs without using loop?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to get data from the database using a list of IDs. I have a model.

```
class Point(models.Model):
    p1 = models.IntegerField()
    p2 = models.IntegerField()
```

This model has bunch of data in my database. I have a list of IDs whose data is available in my database.
`[1,2,3,3,4,1]`

I want to get the data from my list's IDs. I know the solution that I can apply a loop here and get the data by iterating over the list. I was looking for a better solution.

I have seen some similar solution with `Point.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,3,4,1])` but it does not return the objects of repeating values like 1 and 3 in my list's case. I want the queryset to have duplicates values if my list has duplicate values.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The filter function is not returning repeating values because the id of each `Point` object is unique.  Each `Point` object is unique *even if it has the same data*.  Perhaps you want to filter based on one or both of the other fields, `p1` or `p2`?  If I had an idea as to what you are trying to do, and what `[1,2,3,3,4,1]` is trying to represent, I could help further.

Comment: @raphael Thanks for answering.
I want something like this:
[<Point obj(1)>,<Point obj(2)>,<Point obj(3)>,<Point obj(3)>,<Point obj(4)>,<Point obj(1)>]
I'm not sure how I will be able to do this without using a loop.

Comment: To answer your question directly, you can not do what you want without a loop.  Perhaps if you can tell me *why* you need to have the `Point` object appearing multiple times I could give you a better answer.

Comment: I am using that array for further calculations. If that is not possible, I think I need to change my logic. What if I want to extract an array of objects from another type of queryset? For example:
```
class Point(models.Model):
    p1 = models.IntegerField()
    p2 = models.IntegerField()

class Graph(models.Model):
   user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   point = models.ForeignKey(Point, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```
Now I want to get an array of points from the Graph model belonging to a particular user.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, understand this point ...

First, you need a unique identifier for getting an object which has similar values.
For eg., A group of students has two students whose name is the same. We consider it as "Bob".
Now, for identifying the student "Bob" which I have to find, I need his roll no. As we know, roll no. is unique for every student, Likewise your ID list must contain his primary key for identifying which object you want to call.

I hope this answer clears your doubt!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am not sure if that is the right answer.
I want something like this: 
[<Point obj(1)>,<Point obj(2)>,<Point obj(3)>,<Point obj(3)>,<Point obj(4)>,<Point obj(1)>]
I'm not sure how I will be able to do this without using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your comment correctly, then you have placed the `ForeignKey` in the wrong class, since the way you have it now:

```py
class Point(models.Model): 
    p1 = models.IntegerField() 
    p2 = models.IntegerField() 
    
class Graph(models.Model): 
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    point = models.ForeignKey(Point, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

There would be MANY graphs to EACH single point.  It should be tho other way so that you have MANY points to ONE graph:

```py
class Point(models.Model): 
    p1 = models.IntegerField() 
    p2 = models.IntegerField()
    graph = models.ForeignKey(Graph, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
class Graph(models.Model): 
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then, in your view you could get all the `Point`s in your graph like this:

```py
graph = Graph.objects.get(user=..., date_created=...)
# Here is the filter that will give you all Points on the graph:
points = Point.objects.filter(graph=graph)

# If you need the points as an array
points_list = []

for point in points:
    # Your logic here, or if you just need the array you could
    # append to the points_list:
    points_list.append(point)
```

**Please Note**
I understand that this still may use a loop, and that the filter in the `points = Points.objects.filter(graph=graph)` will still not repeat the same point.  Again, even though the `Point` may be the same location, and/or may have other data associated with it, all of which is equal, it is *still* a unique point with it's own **primary key, pk**.

If you still need an array (in Python, arrays are called lists) of `Point`s with repeated **ID**s, then you will have to do a loop, but then the question remains.  Do you *really need the ID's* of the `Points`?  Are you using the **ID** in your calculations?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I am working on solving this with another logic. I think my initial logic has some issues.